# error MSB3823: Non-string resources require the property GenerateResourceUsePreserializedResources to be set to true

Tags: c#, .net, batch-file, .net-core, .net-5

Hello everyone I got an error and I`m trying to solve it I found some similar source but could not solve my problem. Similar problem like [here](https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/issues/4704).

I compile my project `.csproj` file using `.bat` file actually it is `.batch` file from `cmd`. But I got this error:

`error MSB3823: Non-string resources require the property GenerateResourceUsePreserializedResources to be set to true. [C:\Users\rmrud\source\Workspaces\Workspace2\HAL9\v3_07\Test\Test\Test.csproj]`

and also I got this:

```
error MSB3822: Non-string resources require the 
System.Resources.Extensions assembly at runtime, but it was not found in this project's references. [C:\Users\rmrud\source\Workspaces\Workspace2\HAL9\
v3_07\Test\Test\Test.csproj]
```

I also did this run this in cmd `choco install visualstudio2019-workload-netcoretools`.

I edited my `.csproj` file  add these xml node in your `xxx.csproj` file:

```
<PropertyGroup> 
    <GenerateResourceMSBuildArchitecture>
        CurrentArchitecture
    </GenerateResourceMSBuildArchitecture>
    <GenerateResourceMSBuildRuntime>
        CurrentRuntime
    </GenerateResourceMSBuildRuntime>
</PropertyGroup>
```

then again I compile using bat file from cmd but still got build error. How to overcome this thanks in advance. Please Note that in my machine I'm using .NET framework version 4.8 and .Net core 5

Comment: Any updates on this one?

Comment: No Still Trying

Answer (score 25):

Please add **System.Resources.Extensions** NuGet package into an appropriate project.

Comment: I had a similar problem and did a simple-minded "dotnet add package System.Resources.Extensions". It didn't work. Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: @DavePotts, framework or core?

Comment: Framework vs. core was my problem. Not applicable to this question on closer examination. Sorry for confusion!

Comment: @DavePotts how did you add this package? I did Install-Package System.Resources.Extensions, but the build is still error.

Comment: Converting a .Net Framework project to .Net 8.0, this answer solved the problem. Thanks @AntonNorko

Answer (score 8):

If your project is using .NET Framework and you using Resources in it, check if you have this in your csproj file:

```
 <GenerateResourceUsePreserializedResources>true</GenerateResourceUsePreserializedResources>
```

Remove it or set it to false.
Check references for this, it seems that it's used with .NET Core but for NET Framework give false error.

Comment: this is doesn't work.. error MSB3823 shows that I need to add true to this.

Comment: I am converting a .Net 4.8 project to .NET 8.  This tag was missing and I added it to the .NET 8 project, changing it to false.  It resolved the immediate error and unlocked all of the syntax exceptions resulting from the upgrade.